# ActivityTwo.java did not count

Tags: java, android, android-studio, counter

Hello my source code down below ;

This is ActiviyOne.java

```
package course.labs.activitylab;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.Fragment;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityOne
        extends Activity {

    // Use these as keys when you're saving state between reconfigurations
    private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
    private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
    private static final String START_KEY = "start";
    private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

    // String for LogCat documentation
    private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityOne";

    // Lifecycle counters
    // TODO:
    public Integer mCreate = 0;
    public Integer mRestart = 0;
    public Integer mStart = 0;
    public Integer mResume = 0;
    // Create variables named
    // mCreate, mRestart, mStart and mResume
    // to count calls to onCreate(), onRestart(), onStart() and
    // onResume(). These variables should not be defined as static.
    // You will need to increment these variables' values when their
    // corresponding lifecycle methods get called.
    // TODO: Create variables for each of the TextViews
    TextView mTvCreate;
    TextView mTvRestart;
    TextView mTvStart;
    TextView mTvResume;

    // named mTvCreate, mTvRestart, mTvStart, mTvResume.
    // for displaying the current count of each counter variable
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        // TODO: Assign the appropriate TextViews to the TextView variables
        mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
        mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restart);
        mTvResume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resume);
        mTvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
        // Hint: Access the TextView by calling Activity's findViewById()
        // textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Button launchActivityTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchActivityTwo);
        launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO:
                // Launch Activity Two
                // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method
                // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to
                // start
                //Intent intent = null;
                Intent StartIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(StartIntent);
                // Launch the Activity using the intent
            }
        });

        // Has previous state been saved?
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            // TODO:
            // Restore value of counters from saved state
            // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
            mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
            mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
            mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
            mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);
            //Log.i(TAG, "mCreate " + mCreate + "mResume " + mResume + "mStart " + mStart + "mRestart " + mRestart);
            //super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onCreate() method");
        // TODO:
        mCreate++;
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface via the displayCounts() method
    }

    // Lifecycle callback overrides

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStart() method");
        // TODO:
        mStart++;
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onResume() method");
        // TODO:
        mResume++;
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onPause() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStop() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onRestart() method");
        // TODO:
        mRestart++;
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onDestroy() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO:
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
        // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs
        // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
    }

    // Updates the displayed counters
    // This method expects that the counters and TextView variables use the
    // names
    // specified above
    public void displayCounts() {
        // TODO - uncomment these lines
        mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
        mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);
        mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);
        mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);
    }
}
```

And this is ActivityTwo.java

```
    package course.labs.activitylab;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityTwo
        extends Activity {

    // Use these as keys when you're saving state between reconfigurations
    private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";
    private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";
    private static final String START_KEY = "start";
    private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";

    // String for LogCat documentation
    private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityTwo";

    // Lifecycle counters
    // TODO:
    public Integer mCreate = 0;
    public Integer mRestart = 0;
    public Integer mStart = 0;
    public Integer mResume = 0;

    // Create variables named   
    // mCreate, mRestart, mStart and mResume    
    // to count calls to onCreate(), onRestart(), onStart() and
    // onResume(). These variables should not be defined as static.
    // You will need to increment these variables' values when their
    // corresponding lifecycle methods get called.
    // TODO: Create variables for each of the TextViews
    TextView mTvCreate;
    TextView mTvRestart;
    TextView mTvStart;
    TextView mTvResume;
    // named  mTvCreate, mTvRestart, mTvStart, mTvResume.
    // for displaying the current count of each counter variable
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
        // TODO: Assign the appropriate TextViews to the TextView variables
        mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
        mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restart);
        mTvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
        mTvResume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resume);
        // Hint: Access the TextView by calling Activity's findViewById()
        // textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClose);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO:
                    /*
                    Intent FinishIntent = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityOne.class);
                    finish();
                    */
                // This function closes Activity Two
                // Hint: use Context's finish() method
                // ActivityTwo.this.finish();
                // finish();
                //  Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityOne.class);
                finish();
                //ActivityTwo.this.finish();
            }
        });
    /*
            savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
            savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
            savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
            savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
    */
        // Has previous state been saved?
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            // TODO:
            // Log.i(TAG, "Entered restoring values of counters");
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
            mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);
            mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
            mResume = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESUME_KEY);
            //Log.i(TAG, "mCreate " + mCreate + "mResume " + mResume + "mStart " + mStart + "mRestart " + mRestart);
            // Restore value of counters from saved state
            // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
            // super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }
        // Emit LogCat message
        mCreate++;
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onCreate() method");
        // TODO:
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface via the displayCounts() method
    }

    // Lifecycle callback methods overrides

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Emit LogCat message
        mStart++;
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStart() method");
        // TODO:
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Emit LogCat message
        mResume++;
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onResume() method");
        // TODO:
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onPause() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onStop() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        // Emit LogCat message
        mRestart++;
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onRestart() method");
        // TODO:
        displayCounts();
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        // Update the user interface
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Emit LogCat message
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onDestroy() method");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO:
        // Save counter state information with a collection of key-value pairs
        // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving instance state");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(CREATE_KEY, mCreate);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESTART_KEY, mRestart);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(RESUME_KEY, mResume);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(START_KEY, mStart);
    }

    // Updates the displayed counters
    // This method expects that the counters and TextView variables use the
    // names
    // specified above
    public void displayCounts() {
        // TODO - uncomment these lines
        mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
        mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);
        mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);
        mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);
    }
}
```

I have a problem. When i run the program I want the count how many times I called

`onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onResume()` it works for activity one
,but not works in activity 2. Counter not working.

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification, why would you like to know this? I can't think of a use case...

Comment: why not create static field ??

Comment: it is a homework, and in the instructions it is written that  don't use static.

Comment: If you want to do it without any counters and with those log messages you could create a LogRabbit filter that would do that very easily. Just create a filter for "Entered the onPause() method" and when you select that filter you will see exactly how many times that log message appears. This is an example of doing it for JSON: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeildKynnuc I will create a demo of your use case and post it later. This all assumes you are using a Mac. http://lograbbit.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Activity1 state is saved on stack -> when you call Activity2.

2) When click back Activity2 state is saved and then destroyed (removed from stack).

3) Activity1 read saved state from stack.

Try this [Activity 1]:

```
 launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent StartIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);
    StartIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(StartIntent);
            }
        });
```

[Activity 2]:

```
 closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityOne.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please?

Answer (score 3):

You have created the counters as local variables.

```
public Integer mCreate = 0;
public Integer mRestart = 0;
public Integer mStart = 0;
public Integer mResume = 0;
```

So, after Activity2 is destroyed, i.e. after onStop() is called, these variables are also removed.

Solution : Create one new class and create static counter variables inside this.

Answer (score 2):

```
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
```

You should not call this method in `onCreate()`.

You should also use `ActivityOne.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` for your `Intent` that starts `ActivityTwo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from both activity
replace this code from "if (savedInstanceState != null)" mCreate++ replace it with mCreate += 1; and remove the "displaycount()"

for start..restart..resume
mStart +=1;
mRestart +=1;
mResume +=1
and remove the value from public integer mCreate to mResume remove this "0"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.